# Joining Attributes from Layer Limitation in QGIS 3.2?

Tags: qgis, layers, attribute-joins

I want to join two txt-tables as a layer in QGIS 3.2. In earlier versions (QGIS 2.12) works to join one of the tables more times to the other table. Now in version 3.2, I can join only one time. The table that should be joined second-time is not shown in the drop-down menu to select.

Answer (score 1):

A simple Workaround is to just duplicate the layer in layerslist. Then you can perform another join on the same file.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, I can suggest using a `"Virtual Layer"` through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`

Let's assume we have the following layer `"some_points"` with its corresponding attribute table, and one additional CSV-file `"data"` that has to be joined, see image below.

CSV-file can be simply drag&dropped into QGIS working window..

[image: input]

With the following query, it is possible to create a *"new"* shapefile with requested attributes added via joining the CSV-file.

```sql
SELECT sp.*, d."Param 1", d."Param 2"
FROM "some_points" AS sp
LEFT JOIN "data" AS d ON sp.Name = d.Name
```

The output Virtual Layer with its Attribute table will look as following

[image: output]

---

If you want to join several CSV-files at once simply extend the upper query with a needed number of joins that you need, just mind the joining attribute, see the query below.

```sql
SELECT sp.*, d1."Param 1", d2."Param 2"
FROM "some_points" AS sp
LEFT JOIN "data" AS d1 ON sp.Name = d1.Name
LEFT JOIN "data2" AS d2 ON sp.Name = d2.Name
```

*Note:* that instead of `"data2"` in the second join: `LEFT JOIN "data2" AS d2 ON sp.Name = d2.Name` there can be any other CSV-file, shapefile or layer that is loaded into QGIS working window.